# SpriteKit SKShapeNode stops prematurely when colliding due to gravity

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

This is the setup

```
    // Create a scene
    scene = SKScene(size: self.view.frame.size)

    let sceneHeight = scene.frame.height
    let sceneWidth = scene.frame.width

    // Create nodes
    // Rectangle
    let shapeWidth: CGFloat = 100
    let shapeHeight = shapeWidth
    let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, shapeWidth, 100))
    shapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: sceneWidth/2 - shapeWidth/2, y: 300)
    shapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
    shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()

    // Floor
    let floorWidth: CGFloat = sceneWidth
    let floorHeight: CGFloat = 10
    let floorNode = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, floorWidth, floorHeight))
    floorNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
    floorNode.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    floorNode.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    // Create the node tree
    scene.addChild(floorNode)
    scene.addChild(shapeNode)
```

Then I define and add two physics bodies to my two nodes.

```
    // Create physics
    let shapePhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: shapeWidth, height: shapeHeight))
    shapePhysicsBody.dynamic = true
    shapePhysicsBody.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Shape
    shapePhysicsBody.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Floor
    shapePhysicsBody.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    shapePhysicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

    let floorPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: floorWidth, height: floorHeight))
    floorPhysicsBody.dynamic = true
    floorPhysicsBody.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Floor
    floorPhysicsBody.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Shape
    floorPhysicsBody.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    floorPhysicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    floorPhysicsBody.affectedByGravity = false

    // Add physics
    shapeNode.physicsBody = shapePhysicsBody
    floorNode.physicsBody = floorPhysicsBody
    scene.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -1)
    scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

This sort of works, that is the rectangle shape does fall from it's initial position and the collision delegate is called when a collision happens.

The contents of my `didBeginContact:` method.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody   : SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody  : SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody   = contact.bodyA
        secondBody  = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody   = contact.bodyB
        secondBody  = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Floor != 0) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Shape != 0)) {
        secondBody.dynamic = false
        println("collision")
    }
}
```

But the shape node stops way before there's a visual contact. I hope these images give an impression of how that looks.

Starts here
[image: Initial state]

This is where the contact happens
[image: Final state]

Why is there such a gap between them? What am I missing? I want them to visually touch each other before the rectangle stops moving.

Comment: Have you checked is everything is in place with physics bodies? Turn on physics visual representation in your view controller skView.showsPhysics = YES;

Comment: @Whirlwind that is probably the first thing anyone dealing with SpriteKit should do :) thanks!

Comment: Make sure to use SKShapeNode wisely, because shape nodes cannot be drawn in a single pass. Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344235/skshapenode-consuming-too-much-memory-and-slowing-down-animation-spritekit-ios Using SKSpriteNode and initializing it with color would be a better way if you just need colored sprites like in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SKShapeNode(rect:)` draws the `SKShapeNode` with the `node.position` as `origin`. For the `SKPhysicsBody` `position` corresponds to the `center` of the `rectangle`. This creates an offset between the physics body and the actual node. You can see that if you enable

`scene.view?.showsPhysics = true`.

You can correct the offset by creating the `SKShapeNode` using following code.

```
let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRectMake(-shapeWidth/2, -50, shapeWidth, 100))
// Other code
let floorNode = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRectMake(-floorWidth/2, -floorHeight/2, floorWidth, floorHeight))
```

Comment: Still seems a bit strange that they position the `SKPhysicsBody` to the center of the rectangle. Is there a good reason why?